# Is it Possible to create Streaming Replication of Postgresql in Localhost machine?

Tags: postgresql, localhost, devops, replication

I want to create Master & Slave for streaming replication of Postgresql Database in Localhost machine, Is that possible?
Can anyone suggest for further?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. More details are [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION)

Comment: What is your concern?  That they are on the same host?  That the name of that host is 'localhost'?